# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dropzone is not a function

Tags: jquery, .net, model-view-controller, typeerror, dropzone

I'm using dropzone version 4.3 with jQuery version 3.3.1 for my asp.net MVC 5 project.

This is my View. (Index.cshtml)

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/min/dropzone.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/min/dropzone.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    $(function () {
        $("#dZUpload").dropzone({ url: "/Home/Index" });
    });
</script>

<div>
   <div id='dZUpload' class='dropzone'></div>
</div>
```

However, when I run the project, the dropzone does not work as I expected. It returns following error in the browser console.

[image]

I followed the below fixes which mentioned in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56098944/typeerror-dropzone-is-not-a-function).

- move `$("#dZUpload").dropzone({ url: "/Home/Index" });` to the window.onload.
- rename dropzone to Dropzone

Unfortunately, none of those worked.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in a document.ready block:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function () {
        $("#dZUpload").dropzone({ url: "/Home/Index" });
    });
})
```

Comment: I did above and still the same issue. Now it shows one more error saying "Uncaught Error: No URL provided."

Comment: I've edited my answer. Move `Dropzone.autooDiscover` out of the `document.ready`.

Comment: Still the "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dropzone is not a function" error comes